# Using Dovecot on Linux as an email archive repository

Tags: linux, email, dovecot

I am helping a company who has recently moved from one host to another. The new host has an 4.48gb limit for email which the companies emails fills. They don't want to lose the older emails but they want to be able to easily access them (no csv,pdf,etc). I was thinking of setting up a Linux box with Dovecot and moving the old emails (2012-2022) to it and map it through their client (outlook/Thunderbird) for easy access. Is this viable? Any tips on doing this? I am not a Linux person generally and need guidance on situations like this. Thanks

Comment: Its viable if you know what you are doing, however in addition to a knowledge of Linux and mailservers, you're also going to need to do some programming if you want to strip attachments from emails. As it stands your question is off-topic as too vague.